# Backbone.js search with query-strings

Tags: javascript, search, backbone.js

I just started looking at Backbone.js. Now i wan't to create a simple search similar to google where the url updates "on the go". So if you submit a form i want the url to update to http://www.site.com/#/search/I-searched-for-something.

I appreciate every answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want an arbitrary URL that includes your search term as part of the URL.  And I suspect that your problem is you don't see how to do that with the `routes` architecture.

Routes are nothing but regular expressions:

```
var MyController = Backbone.Controller.extend({
    routes: {
        RegExp('^search/(.*)$'): "handle_search"
    },

    handle_search: function(search_term) {
        search_term = decodeURIComponent(search_term);
        /* Do something ajaxy with the search term in the search model,
           which in turn triggers the search view to refresh... */
    }
});
```

After that, you would apply a `click` handler to the button on the search form (or maybe a `keypress==13` manager to the search field itself) that, instead of actually doing anything, just sets `window.location.hash = escapeURIComponent($('#search_field').val())`

It's roundabout, but it gets the job done.  Your URLs will be ugly with all the %XX's in them, but they'll all be bookmarkable, which is the only reason to do something like this.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry for a bad explanation. It was: `window.location.hash = escapeURIComponent($('#search_field').val())` i was looking for :) But what if i have for example two (or more) select menus and want to submit them the same way?

Comment: I'm not clear on the question.  You can make *anything* into a route, and in return, you can route anything through the encode/decodeURIComponent pair.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 1):

Emil, I think I have a similar use case to you where users could make selections and then  trigger a search. I want that search to be updated in the address bar so it can be bookmarked. To update the address bar, I was planning on using [Backbone navigate](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-navigate)

For multiple search terms I plan to 1. set them as values in my the collection and then trigger a fetch on the collection 2. ask the collection for the url and update the address bar using navigate.